# Debugger not finishing the method on step through

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a fairly simple piece of C# code that I use often

```
        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand();
        sql.Connection = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());
        sql.CommandText = @"update [Reporting].[dbo].[Customer_Master]
                            set groupID = @groupID
                            where customer = @customerID";

        sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@groupID", groupID));
        sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer", customer));


        sql.Connection.Open();
        sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sql.Connection.Close();

        sql.Dispose();
```

For some reason it wasn't updating my DB correctly so I decided to add a break point at the beginning of the method and step through each line to make sure my variables were coming in correctly.

However, the method closes after sql.Connection.Open(), as in it just returns me back to the main code.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Edit:  I found the problem.  I had used the wrong param name.  I still find it odd that it closed out the method after opening the connection without throwing an error though.

Comment: Have you wrapped your code in a try/catch block to see what the underlying exception is?

Comment: If the method ends after trying to open the connection it means an unhandled exception is happening.  I must vote this question down for the lack of research done before asking it.

Answer (score 0):

You are either throwing some sort of exception here or it may be a timeout error when you are stepping through .Open. But I agree with dash, start out by putting it in a try/catch, this should always be your first step.

Comment: Thank you, I found the exception, I was just confused about why the application didn't break upon hitting the exception.  That's what I'm used to seeing.  The try/catch will be the first thing i try next next time.